# Haskell record syntax and read from file. String to record syntax. *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

Tags: exception, haskell, syntax, record

I have the below Record Syntax.

```
type Title = String
type Author = String
type Year = Int
type Fan = String


data Book = Book { bookTitle :: Title
                 , bookAuthor:: Author
                 , bookYear  :: Year
                 , bookFans  :: [Fan]
                 }
                 deriving (Show, Read)


type Database = [Book]

bookDatabase :: Database 
bookDatabase = [Book "Harry Potter" "JK Rowling" 1997 ["Sarah","Dave"]]
```

I would like to create an IO function that reads a books.txt file and converts it to type Database. I think it needs to be similar to my attempt below.

```
main :: IO()
main = do fileContent <- readFile "books.txt";
          let database = (read fileContent :: Database)
```

What is the correct format the books.txt file?

Below is my current books.txt content (same as bookDatabase).

```
[Book "Harry Potter" "JK Rowling" 1997 ["Sarah","Dave"]]
```

> *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The derived `Read` instance for records can only read record syntax. It can't read a record that's in the format of a constructor applied to arguments in order. Try putting the following (which is the result of `show bookDatabase`) into `books.txt`.

```
[Book {bookTitle = "Harry Potter", bookAuthor = "JK Rowling", bookYear = 1997, bookFans = ["Sarah","Dave"]}]
```

Answer (score -2):

There are a couple things to fix up in your example.

First, in your datatype declaration, you need to derive a `Read` instance.

```
data Book = Book {
      bookTitle :: String
    , bookAuthor :: String
    , bookYear   :: Int
    , bookFans   :: [String]
    } deriving (Show,Read)
```

Next, if you look at the type of `read`:

```
> :t read
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

you can see its return type is polymorphic. Therefore, to have it parse correctly, you need to let GHC know what kind of type you are expecting to be parsed. Normally, you can just use the parsed value as you normally would and GHC will be able to infer the type:

```
getFans = do
    book <- readFile "book.txt"
    return $ bookFans book
```

but in GHCi you'll have to give it a hint:

```
> let book = Book "the sound and the fury" "faulkner" 1929 ["me"] 
> show book
"Book {bookTitle = \"the sound and the fury\", bookAuthor = \"faulkner\", bookYear = 1929, bookFans = [\"me\"]}"
> read $ show book :: Book
Book {bookTitle = "the sound and the fury", bookAuthor = "faulkner", bookYear = 1929, bookFans = ["me"]}
```

Comment: The question is already using a type signature, `(read fileContent :: Database)`, to tell the compiler that it should be using the `Read` instance for `[Book]`.

Comment: @Cirdec Oh, sure. I missed that. Not sure why that warrants a downvote though. My answer isn't incorrect is it? If it is I'd be glad to learn my mistake. : )

Comment: Your answer is entirely correct, it just doesn't answer the question. The author already has a `Read` instance for `Book`, or wouldn't be able to compile and run `(read fileContent :: Database)` to get the run-time error `Prelude.read: no parse`. The small ghci session you added to the end of your answer demonstrates what `show` does and that `read . show` can be an identity for `Book`s, but doesn't explain why `books.txt` can't be read.

Comment: @Cirdec Well they didn't have a `Read` instance for book when I wrote my answer. The question was edited after the fact. I admit to mistakenly pointing out that `read` needs some type information to operate. I was perhaps too quick to assume that the OP is a beginner, and this behavior would confuse them going forward. I also thought that demonstrating `read . show = id` would indicate the format that `read` expects (i.e. the one produced by show).